# Elastic search aggregation query returns results since 1970?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Hi I am new to elastic search . i am running the following query / rest request to elastic search. I am trying to get a histogram for one year. however the results return data since 1970 instead of data last year to this year.

```
curl -X GET "10.10.9.1:9200/mep-reports*/_search?pretty&size=0" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"query": {

     "bool": {

       "must": [
         { "range": { "@timestamp": {"gte": "now-1y/y" , "lt": "now"}}}
      ]
   }
 },

 "aggs" : {
        "sales_over_time" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "submission_ts",
                "interval" : "day",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
            }                              
        }                                   
    }             

}'
```

the following is the response i recieve. if you check the key_as_string you can see it starts from 1970  . my question is why is it ignoring the specified range `(  { "range": { "@timestamp": {"gte": "now-1y/y" , "lt": "now"}}}`
)

```
{
  "took" : 22,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 12,
    "successful" : 12,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1073013,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "sales_over_time" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "1970-01-19 12:00:00",
          "key" : 1555200000,
          "doc_count" : 1016510
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "1970-01-20 12:00:00",
          "key" : 1641600000,
          "doc_count" : 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "1970-01-21 12:00:00",
          "key" : 1728000000,
          "doc_count" : 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "1970-01-22 12:00:00",
          "key" : 1814400000,
          "doc_count" : 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "1970-01-23 12:00:00",
          "key" : 1900800000,
          "doc_count" : 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "1970-01-24 12:00:00",
          "key" : 1987200000,
          "doc_count" : 0
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "1970-01-25 12:00:00",
          "key" : 2073600000,
          "doc_count" : 0
        },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is on the `@timestamp` field yet your aggregation is on `submission_ts`.

If you want your `date_histogram` aggregation to be bounded by the query, you need to use the same field in both the query and aggregation.

```
curl -X GET "10.10.9.1:9200/mep-reports*/_search?pretty&size=0" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"query": {

     "bool": {

       "must": [
         { "range": { "submission_ts": {"gte": "now-1y/y" , "lt": "now"}}}
      ]
   }
 },

 "aggs" : {
        "sales_over_time" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "submission_ts",
                "interval" : "day",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
            }                              
        }                                   
    }             

}'
```